# Deploy Nodejs Telegram bot on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, telegram-bot

I've built a Telegram bot with Nodejs and Telegraf.js to download torrents to my Raspberry Pi home server, but I couldn't find a way to deploy it, so it works automatically without me having to connect to it via ssh and starting the bot.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/rc.local`, and add below command.

```
/usr/local/bin/node /home/pi/bot_project/Telegraf.js &
```

Please provide the absolute path of `node`.
We can find the correct path with `which node`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!
I've edited `/etc/rc.local` and now it looks like this: 
`_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

node /home/pi/TorrentDownloaderTelegramBot/index.js &

exit 0`

But it still doesn't work... What have I done wrong?